# Subcategories in Category Page

Tags: categories

I'm trying to do a category page where it displays a card layout with the sub-categories of that wordpress category.

Basically i would have "Sports" and inside the page multiple cards with the Categories "basketball" "football" etc...(oof course these are just example categories).

I know how to build the cards etc... i just cant find the php function to fetch all the sub cateogires
for example when we are fetching the articles of one category

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>                    
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

I'm looking for something similar, because all the solutions i have found are for e comerce plug ins and dont work...

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in the Wordpress docs?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

Comment: Yes there was a comment that explained how, to get a drop box..but it didnt work... if that wasnt the case i would have use it...

Comment: Maybe something like this hmm https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/